# swift-format fails with "Library not loaded: @rpath/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib" after Xcode update

Tags: swift, xcode, homebrew

I have `swift-format` (v0.50700.0_1) installed via homebrew with Xcode 14.3.  All was working well and seemingly what changed is I upgraded Xcode (I believe just from 14.2).

Now it tells me:

> Library not loaded: @rpath/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib

The file exists here:
`/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-5.7.3-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib`

Should I just symlink to it from `/usr/bin`?  Is there a better place to reference it?  How was it referencing it before and why did that break?

Comment: ...tried copying to /usr/local/lib and it tells me that the version of the library is not compatible with the version of swift-format, but this page https://github.com/apple/swift-format claims my versions should be correctly aligned.